# Correct use of past perfect?

Tags: grammar, tenses

This is all about one question but I had to create some context for that sentence to make it sound as natural as possible. Is that sentence with past perfect correct?

Telling a story about my best Wimbledon.
....
*After the victory in the third-round match I was so excited. I went to sleep at about three o'clock in the morning. It is usual that you can not fall asleep that quickly when you are full of emotions. That night I wasn't the exception. I could not fall asleep and therefore I opened my favourite book to read - The Alchymist. It was an amazing feeling to know that every win  would bring  something extra special, something unexpected. To be honest I didn´t expect myself to get that far. That Wimbledon **had (already) been** the best tournament in my short career. Nothing could change that feeling.*

I have got two different answers to this and therefore I decided to create this thread to make sure which of them is the one I should believe.

I have also been told that the past perfect here is possible however it may sound as if a children were speaking rather than an adult person - because it is unusual to consider things to be the best immediately after the start of the tournament or so - third round is still closer to the start I would say.

Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Past perfect is correct, because the story is being told well after the event.

At the time the person may have said *this Wimbledon has already been the best...*.

But if they are speaking about it later they need *that Wimbledon had...*